# PL/SQL Deveolper найти связанный объект

Tags: oracle, plsql-developer

Подскажите как можно найти процедуру или пакет, в котором используется конкретная таблица? Из контекстного меню таблицы выбираю "Перейти к" - ничего не происходит. Есть еще методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть универсальный способ - посмотреть системные вью `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`, `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`, `USER_DEPENDENCIES`.

```
select * 
  from all_dependencies
 where owner = 'TABLE_OWNER' 
   and name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Там связи всех объектов со всеми.

Еще можно поискать по исходникам (`ALL_SOURCE`), но там немного дольше и с регистром надо заморачиваться, зато прямо нужную строку найдете.

```
select * 
  from all_source
 where upper(text) like ('%TABLE_NAME%')
 order by line
```